# Magento 2.2.1 - Admin Product Export Problem

Tags: product, importexport, magento-2.2.1

When i try to export product to CSV. My Admin panel get's wierd. Please take a look at the screenshot. The Admin Panel is getting shifted to the Admin Workarea and export never works.

Any help here. Please check the screenshot and check for Red Arrow, The complete Left Admin Panel is getting shifted to content area and product export stops working.

Warm Regards,

Venkatesha

[image]